# conditional matching between variables in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I am trying to find observations within a column that have certain or all the possible values within another column. In this tibble

```
parties <- tibble(class = c("R","R","R","R","R","K","K","K","K","K","K",
                "L","L","L","L"),
       name = c("Party1", "Party2","Party3","Party4","Party5",
               "Party2", "Party4", "Party6","Party7","Party8","Party9",
                "Party2","Party3","Party4","Party10"))
```

I want to find all the "parties" that are in all three classes "R", "K" and "L". Or generally parties that are in class "X" or "Y". I managed to find a solution, using `group_split(class)`, then extracting each table from the list and then lastly performing two semi_joins. That is for the case when I want parties that are in all three `classes`:

```
parties_split <- parties %>%
  group_split(class)

parties_K <- parties_split[[1]]
parties_L <- parties_split[[2]]
parties_R <- parties_split[[3]]

semi_join(parties_K,parties_L, by = "name") %>%
  semi_join(parties_R, by = "name") %>%
  select(-class)

name
<chr>
Party2              
Party4
```

This would work in this case but would not be efficient especially if the number of classes (or observations) that need to match are much larger than three. I am looking in particular for solutions in tidyverse. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
parties %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  filter("K" %in% class, 
         "R" %in% class, 
         "L" %in% class) %>% 
  summarise()

# A tibble: 2 x 1
  name  
  <chr> 
1 Party2
2 Party4
```

EDIT: If you want to work with more than 3 parties you can also use:

```
mask = c("K", "R", "L")
parties %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  filter(all(mask %in% class)) %>% 
  summarise()
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this work for many groups you can use `purrr::reduce` :

```
library(dplyr)

parties %>%
  group_split(class) %>%
  purrr::reduce(semi_join, by = "name") %>%
  select(name)

#   name  
#  <chr> 
#1 Party2
#2 Party4
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
parties %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(cnt = n()) %>% 
   group_by(class) %>% mutate(grpno = group_indices()) %>% ungroup() %>% 
    filter(cnt >= max(grpno)) %>% select(name) %>% distinct()
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  name  
  <chr> 
1 Party2
2 Party4
```

Comment: Yes! I had to make some adjustments in my real dataset because there were duplicates etc. But it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```r
library(tidyverse)

parties %>% 
  group_by(class) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(id = 1) %>%  
  pivot_wider(name, names_from = class, values_from = id) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(!is.na(sum(c_across(where(is.numeric))))) %>% 
  select(name) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   name  
#>   <chr> 
#> 1 Party2
#> 2 Party4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>